# The use of brackets in MySQL password

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to use mysqldump to take a snapshot of my database, however the root password has brackets in and is causing me issues. As far as I knew, I could surround the password with [] in order for it to work but I still have an issue.

What's the correct way to format this?

```
mysqldump -u root -p[(pwdwithbrackets)] databasename > file.sql
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wrap it in quotes.

Better yet, don't pass an argument to `-p` and just type it in when prompted.  Exposing the password in any way is undesirable.

Answer (score 9):

Use shell escape techniques:

```
-p\(pwdwithbrackets\)
```

... or:

```
'-p(pwdwithbrackets)'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid putting passwords in plain text on your command line anyway.

Instead, you can put them in the user's MySQL config file:

```
$ cat > ~/.my.cnf
[client]
user = root
password = [(pwdwithbrackets)]
^D

$ mysqldump databasename > file.sql
```

I tested and confirmed that this works when the password includes square brackets and parentheses.

You can also put the options in any other file, and use it thus:

```
$ mysqldump --defaults-file=myconf.cfg database > file.sql
```